# Estou com dúvida sobre com fazer a parte de locar e devolução

Tags: java

Para isso, vocês devem criar classes:

➢ Item (disponível (boolean), data de empréstimo, data de devolução, nome e
código). Use a classe Calendar para gerenciar as datas.
➢ Livro (autor e período de empréstimo – 14 dias e deve ser atributo estático)
➢ CD (número de faixas e período de empréstimo – 5 dias)
➢ DVD (duração e período de empréstimo – 3 dias)
➢ Cliente (nome, CPF e telefone)
➢ Empréstimo (cliente e item)
➢ Vetor (Interface – insere, remove e pesquisa)
➢ Vetor de Cliente
➢ Vetor de Locação
➢ Vetor de Item

Cheguei até aqui. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
public class Emprestimo {

    static StringBuffer memoria = new StringBuffer();
    static String arquivo = "Emprestimo.txt";

    static void iniciarArquivo() {
        String linha;
        try {

            BufferedReader arqEntrada;
            arqEntrada = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Emprestimo.txt"));
            memoria.delete(0, memoria.length());
            while ((linha = arqEntrada.readLine()) != null) {
                memoria.append(linha + "\n");

            }

            arqEntrada.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException erro1) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arquivo não encontrado.");

        } catch (Exception erro2) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro de leitura!");
        }
    }

    public static void gravarDados() {

        try {

            String arquivo = "Emprestimo.txt";
            BufferedWriter saida;
            saida = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(arquivo, false));
            saida.write(memoria.toString());
            saida.flush();
            saida.close();
        } catch (Exception erro3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro de gravação");
        }
    }


    public static void Locar (){



    }

   public static void Devolver (){


   }


}
```

Comment: Você deve criar uma classe Item, uma classe Livro, uma classe CD, uma classe DVD e uma classe Empréstimo. A classe empréstimo deve ter os campos/atributos cliente e item. Ou seja, o que você fez aí está tudo errado, pois não são esses os campos/atributos de empréstimo. Além disso, em lugar nenhum desse enunciado diz que é para salvar o que quer que seja em arquivos.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver". Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.